# Youtube Player Keep on buffering in IOS 9.3 built with react native

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-native-ios

I Created Ios app with React native which plays youtube videos within the app. I am using webview and Youtube Iframe API to play youtube videos. The app is working fine in IOS tablet with Version 11 but it's not working in IOS tablet with Version 9.3, the player loads the video but it keeps on buffering the video.

Thanks in Advance